# Trying to use my Angular 4 custom component that implements ControlValueAccessor on a Template-Driven form

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms, angular-template, angular-forms

I am using Angular 4.3.6 with typescript version 2.20.  I've created an Angular 4 custom component that implements ControlValueAccessor and wanted to use it on one of my Template-Driven forms but when I try this, the custom component's writeValue and registerOnChange events do not fire.  I've created a custom component before and they work fine on Reactive forms so I'm wondering if it is even possible to use a custom component that implements ControlValueAccessor on a Template-Driven form.  Is this possible?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  (I've edited this post as I now have a clearer idea of the problem.)  Below is my code:

```
            import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter, Input, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
            import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
            import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
            import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';
            import { ConfigLayoutService } from './config-layout.service';

            @Component({
              selector: 'config-layout',
              template: '<div>
        <ul class="clean-list">
          <li>
            <ul class="clean-list" style="height:175px; overflow:auto">
              <li *ngFor="let configlayout of data; trackBy: trackByLayouts | filter:[{Disabled: false}]">
                <label class="input-control radio small-check" style="margin-right:5px!important">
                  <input type="radio" [value]="configlayout" name="cl" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="layoutChanged($event)" />
                  <span class="check"></span>
                  <span class="caption" title="{{configlayout.Description}}">{{configlayout.Name}}</span>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li [title]="value.Description" *ngIf="showImage" [style]="liBackgroundImageStyle">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>',
              providers: [
                {
                  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
                  useExisting: forwardRef(() => ConfigLayoutComponent),
                  multi: true
                },
                ConfigLayoutService
              ]
            })
            export class ConfigLayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor
            {
              @Output() itemChanged: EventEmitter<ConfigLayoutComponent> = new EventEmitter<ConfigLayoutComponent>();

              @Input() public data: any[];
              @Input('IsCabinet') _IsCabinet: boolean = false;

              //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
              //by the Control Value Accessor
              private onTouchedCallback: () => {};
              private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => {};


              @Input() get value(): any
              {
                return this.configLayoutService.configLayoutValue;
              }
              set value(val: any)
              {
                this.configLayoutService.configLayoutValue = val;

                if (this.onChangeCallback)
                {
                  this.onChangeCallback(val);
                }
              }

              constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private commonService: CommonService, private configLayoutService: ConfigLayoutService)
              {

              }

              ngOnInit(): void
              {
                if (!this.value)
                {
                  this.configLayoutService.configLayoutValue = {};
                }
              }

              ngOnChanges(inputs: any): void
              {
                if (this.value)
                {
                  if (this.onChangeCallback)
                  {
                    this.onChangeCallback(this.value);
                  }
                }
              }

              writeValue(value: any): void
              {
                if (value)
                {
                  this.value = value;
                }
              }

              registerOnChange(fn: any): void
              {
                this.onChangeCallback = fn;
              }

              registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
              {
                this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
              }

              ngOnDestroy()
              {
                this.value = undefined;
              }

              get imgFileName(): any
              {
                let name: string = "";

                if (this.value != null)
                {
                  name = this.value.ImageFileName;
                }

                return name;
              }

              get liBackgroundImageStyle(): any
              {
                let style: any = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("width:348px;height:211px;margin-top:5px!important;border-top: grey 1px solid; background: url(CoreIVCli/src/layoutimages/" + this.imgFileName + ") no-repeat;");

                return style;
              }

              get showImage(): boolean
              {
                let show: boolean = false;

                if (this.value != null)
                {
                  show = this.value.ImageFileName != null;
                }

                return show;
              }

              layoutChanged(config: any)
              {
                this.itemChanged.emit(config);
              }

              get configLabel(): string
              {
                let label: string = "Rack";

                if (this._IsCabinet)
                {
                  label = "Cabinet";
                }

                return label;
              }

              trackByLayouts(index: number, config: any)
              {
                return config.Id;
              }
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you use ControlValueAccessor in your component ?

Comment: So my component can be bound to ngModel so when the radio buttons are clicked, the value for the component will be updated with the value of the selected radio button via the ngModel.

Comment: ControlValueAccessor is mainly a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM. I think it's not a good idea to use a ControlValueAccessor to establish communication between a child and its parents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am using it for what it was intended to be used.  I used it before successfully and was unsure what I was doing wrong in this instance.